# PyCharm debugger stopping containers after "Waiting for connection" ends

Tags: debugging, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I am trying to debug docker-compose containers in PyCharm.

Here is how my run configuration looks like:

[image]

Note that it is a Django app. When I try to start the debugger it is successfully starting all containers and I can access the app on the browser for a short amount of time. Also there is a background task running "Waiting for connection"

[image]

Right after it ends, the containers are suddenly stopped.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: running into the same issue here, have you figured out why exactly this occurs or stops occuring when you change your entrypoint?

Comment: @pascalwhoop unfortunately no. I personally asked JetBrains guys themselves in a DjangoCon conference. After spending around an hour, they didn't know either.

Comment: I have the same issue in our large project but a fresh simple minimalist project works fine. I suspect it's got something to do with either our Docker image or the fact that django does some magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to fix this:

1. Moved the entrypoint to the docker-compose file instead of the Dockerfile
2. Changed the port to `8000` from `8050`

I have no idea why this matters but it fixed it.